# Replicating CPU-Intensive Animation with HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, browser

I'm attempting to replicate an animation similar to this one: https://imgur.com/8rAXdYL. However, I'm facing significant CPU performance issues, causing the browser to become unresponsive.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Initially, I attempted to recreate the animation using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, with a canvas element for the main animation. However, this approach proved to be too heavy on the CPU, resulting in poor performance.
I then experimented with duplicating the canvas to simulate a "tracking" motion, but this only exacerbated the performance issues.
Additionally, I've optimized my code by reducing unnecessary calculations and minimizing DOM manipulations, but the performance problems persist.
I'm seeking guidance on how to achieve a smoother animation experience without overburdening the CPU. Are there alternative approaches or techniques I could use to create this animation more efficiently? Could someone provide insights or suggestions on how to optimize the animation code for better performance?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let width, height, radius;
let particles = [];
const numParticles = 600; // Increased number of particles for higher density
const particleRadius = 1; // Particle radius
const fadeOutThreshold = 20; // Threshold distance from edge for particles to start fading out

// Function to center the canvas and update its size
function centerCanvas() {
  width = window.innerWidth * 0.25; // Increased canvas width
  height = window.innerHeight * 0.5; // Increased canvas height
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2; // Circular boundary radius
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  canvas.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2 - width / 2) + 'px';
  canvas.style.top = (window.innerHeight / 2 - height / 2) + 'px';
}

// Call the centerCanvas function initially and on window resize
centerCanvas();
window.addEventListener('resize', centerCanvas);

class Particle {
  constructor(x, y, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velocity = {
      x: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2,
      y: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2
    };
    this.color = color;
    this.opacity = 1; // Initial opacity
  }

  draw(context) {
    context.globalAlpha = this.opacity;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, particleRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.fill();
    context.globalAlpha = 1;
  }

  update() {
    this.draw(ctx);

    this.x += this.velocity.x;
    this.y += this.velocity.y;

    // Keep particles within the canvas boundaries
    if (this.x < 0 || this.x > width || this.y < 0 || this.y > height) {
      const distanceFromEdge = Math.min(this.x, width - this.x, this.y, height - this.y);
      if (distanceFromEdge < fadeOutThreshold) {
        this.opacity -= 0.01; // Reduce opacity when particles are close to the edge
      }
    }

    if (this.opacity < 0) {
      this.opacity = 0; // Ensure opacity doesn't go below 0
    }
  }
}

// Initialize particles with higher density
function initializeParticles() {
  particles = [];
  const desiredNumParticles = 300; // Desired number of particles
  const particleGap = Math.sqrt((width * height) / desiredNumParticles); // Adjust particle gap based on desired number
  for (let x = 0; x < width; x += particleGap) {
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y += particleGap) {
      const color = '#6A73AE';
      particles.push(new Particle(x, y, color));
    }
  }
}
initializeParticles();

// Function to continuously spawn new particles and remove faded-out particles
function updateParticles() {
  particles.forEach((particle, index) => {
    if (particle.opacity <= 0) {
      particles.splice(index, 1); // Remove faded-out particles
    }
  });

  while (particles.length < numParticles) {
    const x = Math.random() * (width - particleRadius * 2) + particleRadius;
    const y = Math.random() * (height - particleRadius * 2) + particleRadius;
    const color = '#6A73AE';
    particles.push(new Particle(x, y, color)); // Add new particles
  }
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  particles.forEach(particle => {
    particle.update();
  });
  updateParticles(); // Update particles array
}

animate();

// Function to create a new canvas following the mouse, fade it out, and remove it
function createFollowingCanvas(event) {
  const newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const newCtx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
  const newCanvasSize = Math.min(width, height); // Size of the new canvas
  const fadeOutTime = 500; // Duration before fade-out
  const fadeOutInterval = 20; // Interval for opacity reduction, increased for smoother animation
  const mouseX = event.clientX;
  const mouseY = event.clientY;

  newCanvas.width = newCanvasSize;
  newCanvas.height = newCanvasSize;
  newCanvas.style.position = 'absolute';
  newCanvas.style.left = (mouseX - newCanvasSize / 2) + 'px';
  newCanvas.style.top = (mouseY - newCanvasSize / 2) + 'px';

  document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let opacity = 1;
    const fadeOutIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
      newCtx.clearRect(0, 0, newCanvasSize, newCanvasSize);
      particles.forEach(particle => {
        particle.draw(newCtx); // Draw particles on the new canvas
      });
      opacity -= 1 / (fadeOutTime / fadeOutInterval);
      // console.log('Opacity:', opacity); // Debug output
      newCanvas.style.opacity = opacity; // Set opacity on the canvas element
      if (opacity <= 0) {
        clearInterval(fadeOutIntervalId);
        document.body.removeChild(newCanvas); // Remove the canvas once faded out
        //console.log('Canvas removed');
        resolve(); // Resolve the promise when fade-out is complete
      }
    }, fadeOutInterval);
  });
}

// Event listener to create a new canvas following the mouse on mousemove
const throttleDelay = 100; // Throttle delay in milliseconds
let lastMouseMove = 0; // Variable to track the time of the last mousemove event

// Throttle mousemove event to reduce the number of animation triggers
$(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  const now = Date.now();
  if (now - lastMouseMove >= throttleDelay) {
    lastMouseMove = now;

    const mouseX = e.clientX - width / 2;
    const mouseY = e.clientY - height / 2;
    $('#canvas').css({
      'left': mouseX,
      'top': mouseY
    });

    // Create a new canvas following the mouse with fade-out effect
    createFollowingCanvas(e)
      .then(() => {
        //console.log('Fade-out complete');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Animated Dots Inside Circle</title>


  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    canvas {
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- First Canvas container -->
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: does it help to enable "hardware acceleration" in browser? maybe get a better cpu or reduce the particle count, or increase the throttle delay

Comment: I put your code into a snippet, for me on my high-end nasa-computer it is very smooth animation :)

Comment: setting throttledelay to 5 it really looks smooth for me when moving the mouse

Comment: Thanks a lot, also your nasa computer comment had me cackling xD

It does look smooth but it doesn't really match the animation I'm trying to copy  https://imgur.com/8rAXdYL

I tried to get as close as I can but I'm not sure how to do the sun like shape of the animation.

While the mouse isn't moving dots are generated outside of the circle and fade, couldn't get it to work like that.